# JDK Documentation searchable offline?

Tags: documentation, javadoc, java

Can anyone help?

i have downloaded the jdk docs (7) to my pc and i can open it up to look at all the packages and classes in the html but it appears i can't search.

You can on the online version but it appears not on the offline version, or maybe i am missing something.

can anyone help or suggest an alternative ?

thanks

Comment: what if you use the finder that your operating system provides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [Java Documentation in Microsoft Windows Help Formats](http://java.sun.com/docs/windows_format.html)

Answer (score 1):

And then there is the frame-using index.html and just use your browsers search to find a class?

Comment: browsers search only searches the contents of the page, i was hoping for something like this http://search.oracle.com/search/search?search_p_main_operator=all&group=Documentation&q=string+format+url%3A%2Fjavase&searchField=string+format&docsets=

Comment: so you need to search the class description text? I would use grep for that but in windows i would probably try using windows search tools by searching for a file which contains text xxx from directory yyy